# How do I switch machines without getting kicked from a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to play on a Minecraft server with a queue. I've installed a program called [Minecraft Console Client](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1263927-win-mac-linux-minecraft-console-client?page=105), and I'm currently running it on a **Ubuntu Terminal Only** system. My question is:

**How can I switch from my Ubuntu to my gaming PC without getting kicked from the server and having to re-queue?**

When I'm logged on on the Ubuntu using Console Client everything is fine. I can leave and when I come back I'm still connected. The problem is that when I want to play on the server I have to switch to my normal PC. But when I log on to the server using my PC I get an error message and both my Ubuntu and my PC get kicked back to the Multiplayer screen. I really want this to work, and I've already dedicated way to much time into it. Please help!

Comment: Not gonna put this as an answer, as I have no proper sources and who knows, maybe it is possible, but Minecraft is not designed that way to allow seamless switching of machines. The game expects only one login at a time, hence the throwback to the multiplayer screen. Unless the server or the queue is modified to keep you connected while you relog on a different machine i fear it is impossible to switch seamlessly.

Comment: So when you disconnect from the sever and connect again, you don't have to wait? What happens if you disconnect and reconnect from/to the internet?

Comment: Why not just enter the queue on your gaming PC, instead of your Ubuntu box?

Comment: @Zymus It takes too much power

Answer (score 2):

## You cannot

Minecraft doesn't allows multiconnection, just one login at time. If you disconnect from a server with queue login you lose the priority, you cannot switch your machine.

You can hope for some implementation of plugins that allow the server to reserve a spot for instant reconnections, but you have to ask the admins for that.

Comment: But Isn't there a way to move the connection to a different pc through some kind of program, without affecting the connection of the server?

Comment: @TheColorman No. The queue would have to be rewritten to allow the same person (not socket) to connect, and even then, depending on how the networking layer was written (blocking vs non-blocking), there might be a hardware-level queue of connections in the pending state, waiting for the service to accept the connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can download MCC to your gaming PC, then it shouldn't draw too much CPU/memory and it might be possible to switch clients that way, unfortunately im not experienced at all in this field, i just happened to have the same idea.

but i would recommend searching for/creating a mod that does the same thing with your Java client, eg. it turns off terrain rendering completely etc...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).